# How to redirect incoming IPs to specific eth?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I'm using a storage server to work and share large video files among co-workers (weddings, events...)
Server has 2 ethernet cards with 2 different internet providers.

We have different internet providers @home. We work from home.

One of the providers has awful speed with the other providers (peering I think is called) so when connected to server from this provider we barely reach 3mbit speed. That's why the second eth card.

So when we use ftp each connects to desired provider but we also use a media server which is over http and here comes the question:

**How to redirect incoming connections from specific ip's from this provider to ethernet card of the same provider?**

I have some basic linux skills and thinking of iptables `nat PREROUTING`

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the server have two IP addresses (one from each provider), or just one (shared across both providers via BGP)?

Comment: Server has 2 ip addresses one from each provider.

Comment: Even if you did some internal redirection, nothing would change. The path for the connection is already set by the time traffic arrives at your server. What is it that you hope to achieve?

Comment: I hope to achieve redirecting users of internet provider X to ethernet card of internet provider X and to be able to play 5mbps to 20mbs without buffering.

Comment: Are your users _connecting to_ the IP address that was issued by provider X, or to the one issued by provider Y?

Comment: If your media server runs on apache, you may create an HTTP redirect rule based on `%{REMOTE_HOST}`. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html for ideas.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll check it out. We're running plex media server because it's easy to use. I have to check which http service is using.